# Pre-filled forms in PopUp Modal ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to use a popup modal to edit a record on ASP.NET Core MVC. I have not been successful to prefill the modal form with the existing record on the edit functionality. 
Below is my simple model:

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

I put a list of the object on the controller just for an example. Below is my controller:

```
public Home: Controller
{
    public static List<Student> studentList = new List<Student>()
    {
        new Student {StudentId = 1, Name = "John"},
        new Student {StudentId = 2, Name = "Doe"},
    };

    public IActionResult Index
    {
        return View(studentList);
    }

    public IActionResult Find(int id)
    {
        var student = studentList.Where(x => x.StudentId == id).FirstOrDefault();
        return new JsonResult(student);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("updateStudent")]
    public IActionResult updateStudent(int id, int name)
    {
        var student = studentList.Where(x => x.StudentId == id).FirstOrDefault();
        studentList.RemoveStudent();
        var newStudent = new Student{StudentId = id, Name=name};
        studentList.Add(newStudent);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

And in my view, I am using Jquery, ajax, and bootstrap for my modal. Below is part of my view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[data-google="tooltip"]').tooltip();

        $('table .edit').on('click', function () {
            var id = $(this).parent().find('.id').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/Home/Find/' + id,
                success: function(student) 
                {
                     $('#editStudentModal #id').val(student.StudentId);
                     $('#editStudentModal #id').val(student.Name);
                }
            })
        })
    });
</script>

<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>StudentId</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StudentId)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="#editStudentModal" class="edit" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">&#xE254;</i></a>
                                <input type="hidden" class="id" value="item.id" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>


<!--Edit Modal Html-->
    <div id="editStudentModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <form method="post" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="updateStudent">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Student</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Id</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" name="id" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" name="name" />
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancel" />
                        <input type="Submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Save" />
                        <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But when I click the edit button, it the modal pops up but it is not prefilled with the chosen record. Can anyone help mt to fix this issue? I suspect something is wrong with my ajax.

Thanks

Comment: The syntax highlighting is revealing a syntax error in your JavaScript: `$('#editStudentModal #id).val.(student.Name);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always press F12 to check the dev tools to find what the error is.In you case, there are several mistakes.

1.`<input type="hidden" class="id" value="item.id" />`

You need to use `@item.id` or `@item.StudentId`(based on the demo) to get the value while you are missing `@` in the code.

2.`$('#editStudentModal #id').val(student.StudentId);`

Then you could use `console.log(student)` in ajax success to check the returned json:

```
{studentId: 1, name: "John"}
```

So, you need to use `student.studentId` instead of `student.StudentId`.

3.Besides, since you use `$('#editStudentModal #id')`, it will find `id="id"` but you only set `name="id"`, add id on the input or use below code to find the element:

```
$('#editStudentModal input[name="id"]').val(student.studentId);
$('#editStudentModal input[name="name"]').val(student.name);
```

**Complete Code**

```
@model List<Student>

<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>StudentId</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StudentId)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#editStudentModal" class="edit" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">&#xE254;</i></a>
                    <input type="hidden" class="id" value="@item.StudentId" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>


<!--Edit Modal Html-->
<div id="editStudentModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form method="post" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="updateStudent">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Student</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Id</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required"  name="id" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required"  name="name" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancel" />
                    <input type="Submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Save" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('[data-google="tooltip"]').tooltip();

            $('table .edit').on('click', function () {
                var id = $(this).parent().find('.id').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '/Home/Find/' + id,
                    success: function (student) {
                        console.log(student);
                        $('#editStudentModal input[name="id"]').val(student.studentId);
                        $('#editStudentModal input[name="name"]').val(student.name);
                    }
                })
            })
        });
    </script>

}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to move the part of HTML that should be shown in the dialog into a `PartialView`.

Insert a new method into the controller with `[HttpGet]` which returns

```
// var model = create the view model based on the parameters you passed into the controller method and pass it to the PartialView.
return PartialView("YourPartialViewName", model);
```

In the Ajax `done` or `success` event, you can use

```
$('#IdOfTheContainerWhereThePartialViewShouldBeRendered').html(student);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to get the elements by id and fill their values.

```html
<!--declare hidden field-->
<input type="hidden" class="hdnId" value="@student.Id" />

<script>
    $('table #editStudentId').on('click', function () {
        var id = $(this).parent().find('.hdnId').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/StudentManager/GetStudentbyId/' + id,
            success: function (student) {
                console.log(student);
                $('#EditStudent input[id="studentId"]').val(student.id);
                $('#EditStudent input[id="studentFirstName"]').val(student.firstName);
                $('#EditStudent input[id="studentLastName"]').val(student.lastName);
                $('#EditStudent select[id="studentRole"]').val(student.Role);
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```